# Microsoft Graph To Do Tasks - Without User Login - Possible?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am wanting to have a server add a To Do task after a specific event occurs by PayPal webhook. Is it possible to have a background service read and create To Do  tasks?

**Background:**

While Requesting API Permissions, the `Tasks.ReadWrite` permission is only available under Delegated Permissions - not Application Permissions.

[image]
Executing a curl request at /token returns a Bearer access_token, but a secondary request targeting /me/todo/lists returns:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
> You
> do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
> credentials that you supplied.

In the [Use the Microsoft To Do API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation is the phrase:

> Currently, the API supports only permissions delegated by the
> signed-in user.

I'm having a bit of a time with the many possibilities for authenticating, permissions and consent. All this prompts the question: Is it possible to have a background service read and create tasks?

**Related**: [Access tenants Microsoft Graph from daemon app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870269/access-tenants-microsoft-graph-from-daemon-app?rq=1)

Comment: It seems that it does not support `application permissions`, then you have to log in as a user.

Comment: The `daemon` is based on the `client credential flow` without user interaction. In your question, you can only use `delegated permissions`, so you should use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Comment: @CarlZhao Is it true the `auth_code flow` requires user interaction? I need this to be done without user sign-on.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to log in as a user, the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) has already stated very clearly:  **Currently, the API supports only permissions delegated by the signed-in user.**

Comment: @David The api required delegated permission so that you must offer a user for generate access token. But as you said that your app is a daemon app, so I think you can hard code a user account & its password(such as admin account) in your code,and use it to generate token via ropc flow.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments, it does **not support** `application permissions`, you should use `delegated permissions` and then call the `/me` endpoint.

Therefore, you must log in as a user. If you do not want to log in interactively, you can also use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, it seems that using the ROPC flow with To Do still does not allow background login.

Comment: @David   I agree with tiny, maybe you can hard-code the username and password in the back-end code.